# Center custom glyph in a CSS pseudo element

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, pseudo-element

I have define a "cross" like symbol in a svg file as

```
<glyph unicode="&#xe604;" d="M784.646 720.646c-30.038 30.038-79.328 30.038-109.367 0l-163.282-163.282-163.282 163.282c-30.038 30.038-79.328 30.038-109.367 0s-30.039-79.328 0-109.367l163.282-163.282-163.282-163.282c-30.039-30.038-30.039-79.328 0-109.367s79.328-30.038 109.367 0l163.282 163.282 163.282-163.282c30.038-30.038 79.328-30.038 109.366 0s30.038 79.328 0 109.367l-163.282 163.282 163.282 163.282c30.038 30.038 30.038 79.328 0 109.366z" />
```

And I tried to put this icon to a pseudo element in css as I have html

```
<span class="icon icon-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
```

and css

```
.icon-close:before {
  content: '\e604';
  color: #474747;
}
```

But the cross in the element is drifting by 1 pixel depending on the place the popup appears on the screen (the cross icon is meant to be the close button on the popup)

drift to left:[image: left drifting] 
drift to right:[image: right drifting] (I give the psuedo element a grey background to illustrate clearer)

Do you have any ideas why this happens and how should I make the icon stick to the center?

Comment: Try adjusting the font size, it could be a glitch. It happened for me with FontAwesome.

Comment: Try using icomoon service and nevertheless, which parameters did you use to generate this font?

Comment: @Ciprian Thanks for your advice but resizing is not working in my case..

Comment: @FelipeAls I did found the font is generated from icomoon, but I did not know the parameters been used when genrating, maybe I should check...

Comment: Then try not giving the box a fixed width and height, but add a padding. This way the padding would drift instead of the symbol, and it would be unnoticeable.

Comment: @FelipeAls I found in the svg file these: font-face units-per-em="1024" ascent="960" descent="-64" , are these the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making this with only pseudo elements?

Something like:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: gray;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
div:before {
  content: "+";
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 8;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  background: gray;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px lightgray;
}
div:hover:after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px tomato;
}
div:hover:before {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment jbutler but this is a great work around but will not actually be the solution to my issue since transform is not supported down to older IEs.